# clap - how to pass a default_value when returning ArgMatches<'static>

Tags: rust, clap

To reduce lines of code I moved my [clap](https://github.com/clap-rs/clap) `App` to another file with something like this:

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=17960e562568d3e254a21307ef512c65)

```
use clap::{App, AppSettings, Arg, ArgMatches}; // 2.33.3
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    let s3m_dir = Path::new("/tmp").join(".s3m");

    let matches = get_matches(s3m_dir.display().to_string());
    println!("{:#?}", matches);
}

pub fn get_matches(home_dir: String) -> ArgMatches<'static> {
    App::new("s3m")
        .version(env!("CARGO_PKG_VERSION"))
        .setting(AppSettings::SubcommandsNegateReqs)
        .after_help(format!("foo bar: {}", home_dir).as_ref())
        .arg(
            Arg::with_name("config")
                .help("config.yml")
                .long("config")
                .short("c")
                .default_value(&format!("{}/.s3m/config.yml", home_dir))
                .required(true)
                .value_name("config.yml"),
        )
        .get_matches()
}
```

The problem I have is that I don't know how could I use the argument `home_dir` as the `default_value`, here:

```
.default_value(&format!("{}/.s3m/config.yml", home_dir))
```

The signature for [default_value](https://docs.rs/clap/2.33.3/clap/struct.Arg.html#method.default_value) is:

```
pub fn default_value(self, val: &'a str) -> Self
```

How could I pass a `format!("{}/.s3m/config.yml", home_dir` with a lifetime in other to satisfy the signature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't used `clap`, so there may be a better approach, but the general Rust solution to this problem is to have some data structure that owns the needed strings, so that the `ArgMatches` can have a lifetime dependent on it:

```rust
struct ArgParser {
    home_dir: PathBuf,
    default_config: OsString,
}

impl ArgParser {
    pub fn new(home_dir: &Path) -> Self {
        let default_config_path: PathBuf = home_dir.join(".s3m/config.yml");
        Self {
            home_dir: home_dir.to_owned(),
            default_config: default_config_path.as_os_str().to_owned(),
        }
    }
```

I've also adjusted the config path to use `Path::join` rather than string formatting and `OsString` instead of `String`, which aren't actually relevant to your question but should be more correct.

Now we can modify `get_matches` to work with this, as part of `impl ArgParser`:

```rust
    pub fn get_matches(&self) -> ArgMatches {
        App::new("s3m")
            .version(env!("CARGO_PKG_VERSION"))
            .setting(AppSettings::SubcommandsNegateReqs)
            .after_help(format!("foo bar: {}", self.home_dir.display()).as_ref())
            .arg(
                Arg::with_name("config")
                    .help("config.yml")
                    .long("config")
                    .short("c")
                    .default_value_os(&self.default_config)
                    .required(true)
                    .value_name("config.yml"),
            )
            .get_matches()
    }
}
```

Notice that there is no lifetime parameter given for `ArgMatches`. This is because the compiler will automatically infer the lifetime for us, as if we had written:

```rust
pub fn get_matches<'a>(&'a self) -> ArgMatches<'a> {...}
```

The lifetime is no longer `'static`, but it *can't* be `'static` (unless you choose to *leak* the strings that you're configuring `App` with). Instead, if you you need a string to live longer than the `ArgParser`, use `.to_owned()` to convert `&'a str` into a `String` that can live independently.

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=44511283ea49194a245104db6abc8dca)